Как присвоить значение глобальной переменной VBA?
Как присвоить значение глобальной переменной VBA при открытии формы и далее изменять её значение при нажатии кнопки? Вторую часть вопроса знаю как сделать. Заранее спасибо.
Если подробнее, то есть счётчик, значение которого надо определить вне процедуры нажатия кнопки.
Public counter As Long
Set (counter, 1) ' counter=1

...
Public Sub ButtonAdd_Click()
counter = counter+1
End Sub


Скорее всего, как сделать переменную глобальной. Вот недавно отвечал.

В VBA глобальные переменные можно объявить в модуле проекта, но нельзя в модуле рабочего листа, книги или формы. Присваивать им значения и читать значения как обычно.

Переменные, объвленные как 'Public' в модуле рабочего листа, книги или формы, являются членами (полями) соответствующих объектов, и доступ к ним только через имя объекта, причём форму нужно предварительно загрузить командой 'Load'.
P. S.
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
  counter = 3
End Sub


Тут два варианта: при открытии книги или при инициализации формы

Спасибо за информацию! Но речь идет оприсвоении значения глабальной переменной, а не об её объявлении. Чуть подправила вопрос, чтобы было понятнее.

counter = 1 присваиваем значение. Опять же вопрос, наверно, о том, где это сделать? Это может быть, нпример, процедура 'Workbook_Open',которая обрабатівает событие открытия книги.

Да, в процедуре кнопки ButtonAdd. А мне надо глобально. Чтобы не при нажатии на кнопку counter каждый раз counter инициализировался 1, а только 1 раз при открытии формы.

Тогда в инициализаторе формы, см. ответ

нет, не при открытии книги, а при открытии формы

Спасибо за помощь!!!
